# Calling function after .load completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

On this web page I have a copy function that uses flash swf.  I load the contents to be copied just before setting up the copy.  I do this with the .load().  But it seems that .load is asynchronous.  Is there a way to call `setup_copy` after the .load is done?  How can I make sure of this?

```
    $('#commentary').load('commspanish.php');
    setup_copy('copy_commentary','commentary');
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method before asking.

Comment: There is a section entitled **Callback Function** [in the `.load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/). For future reference, try starting with the documentation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) *complete* callback:

```
$('#commentary').load('commspanish.php', function() {
  setup_copy('copy_commentary','commentary');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.load` takes a callback:

```
$(...).load(str, function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding second argument of load a response callback function could do that for you. Give some function and it will be called after load is completed, about [**load**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#commentary').load('commspanish.php', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#commentary").load('commspanish.php', function () {
   setup_copy('copy_commentary', 'commentary');
});
```

You could also make it synchronous with `.ajaxSetup`, but why?

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#commentary').load('commspanish.php', function(){
setup_copy('copy_commentary','commentary');
});
```